# Having a Redis Timeout/Replica issue

Tags: redis, timeout, readonly

We are currently having a few issues with our program with Redis that happen and occur randomly. We do not understand what is going on.

The code is open source as well if anyone wants to tag in and help on these two repos:

https://github.com/pythonology/BeatTogether.Core

https://github.com/pythonology/BeatTogether.MasterServer/tree/feature/dedicated-servers (using the branch at the moment for dev purposes)

```
2020-12-10 03:22:17.829 +00:00 [ERR] An error occurred while handling message (MessageType='BroadcastServerStatusRequest').
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: ERR Error running script (call to f_dce2ce9e149bc775618a47cd07eca24d80a33664): @user_script:4: @user_script: 4: -READONLY You can't write against a read only replica.
   at BeatTogether.MasterServer.Data.Implementations.Repositories.ServerRepository.AddServer(Server server) in /app/BeatTogether.MasterServer.Data/Implementations/Repositories/ServerRepository.cs:line 80
   at BeatTogether.MasterServer.Kernel.Implementations.UserService.BroadcastServerStatus(MasterServerSession session, BroadcastServerStatusRequest request) in /app/BeatTogether.MasterServer.Kernel/Implementations/UserService.cs:line 156
   at BeatTogether.Core.Messaging.Implementations.BaseMessageHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2.<<Register>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location --
```

and

```
2020-12-10 06:20:23.198 +00:00 [ERR] An error occurred while handling message (MessageType='BroadcastServerStatusRequest').
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is active/available to service this operation: EVAL, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: master-server, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=1024,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1 source, Exception unthrownException) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2760
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at BeatTogether.MasterServer.Data.Implementations.Repositories.ServerRepository.AddServer(Server server) in /app/BeatTogether.MasterServer.Data/Implementations/Repositories/ServerRepository.cs:line 80
   at BeatTogether.MasterServer.Kernel.Implementations.UserService.BroadcastServerStatus(MasterServerSession session, BroadcastServerStatusRequest request) in /app/BeatTogether.MasterServer.Kernel/Implementations/UserService.cs:line 156
   at BeatTogether.Core.Messaging.Implementations.BaseMessageHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2.<<Register>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at BeatTogether.Core.Messaging.Implementations.BaseMessageSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<Signal>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Our redis instance doesn't have slaves, only a master and its one instance on the same machine.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.